# How to configure APP Id, API key and Base URL in this particular guide on git hub?

Tags: angularjs, api, ionic-framework, stamplay

https://github.com/Stamplay/stamplay-ebayclassifieds

I have been following the guide in the link above to build an app but now I'm stuck at the bit where they ask you to configure app id etc. I am not sure how to edit the app.js file to include these details

Please help!!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.  For instance, do you mean that you don't know how to run an editor?  That you can't fine the app.js file?  Or something else?

Comment: Could you describe what you tried so far? what the actul problem is and what you need help with?

Comment: Thanks guys! I downloaded noteeditor ++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to edit line 24-26 in the app.js and put in the credentials from our stamplay.com account.

```
.constant('APPID', '')
.constant('APIKEY','')
.constant('BASEURL', '') // e.g. http://APPID.stamplay.com
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this already and then emulated the app on android sdk. But the app doesn't seem to open up and gives the error 'cannot connect to server android/www/..

Comment: Hey @RuzinSaleem just saw this apologies for the late reply. Did you solved your problem?